# Is there a compatibility mode provided by OS X CommonCrypto for OpenSSL EVP_* calls (like there is for OpenSSL MD5 functions)?

Tags: c, macos, openssl, commoncrypto

Compiling one of my source files on Mac OS X10.7 and getting these deprecation warnings:

```
xxx_evp.c:135:5: 'EVP_MD_CTX_init' is deprecated
xxx_evp.c:137:9: 'EVP_DigestInit_ex' is deprecated
xxx_evp.c:177:9: 'EVP_DigestUpdate' is deprecated
xxx_evp.c:227:13: 'EVP_DigestFinal_ex' is deprecated
xxx_evp.c:235:5: 'EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup' is deprecated
```

I had another set of OpenSSL deprecation warnings where I was using MD5 functions from `openssl/md5.h` and was able to switch to a CommonCrypto version of the OpenSSL calls like this:

```
#if defined(__APPLE__)
#  define COMMON_DIGEST_FOR_OPENSSL
#  include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#else
#  include <openssl/md5.h>
#endif
```

But I can't find anything offhand about any kind of OpenSSL compatibility related to these `EVP_*` calls. Is there something similar I can do to get "free" compatibility support on OS X 10.7 for these OpenSSL `EVP_*` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in the CommonCrypto headers files in `/usr/include/CommonCrypto/` and the only one that notes any OpenSSL compatibility is `CommonDigest.h`. When the `#define` symbol `COMMON_DIGEST_FOR_OPENSSL` is defined before this header file is included your code, then the following classes of OpenSSL functions are mapped to their CommonCrypto equivalents:

- `MD2_xxx`, `MD4_xxx` and `MD5_xxx`
- `SHA_xxx`, `SHA1_xxx`, `SHA224_xxx`, `SHA256_xxx`, `SHA384_xxx` and `SHA512_xxx`

There does not appear to be any such mapping of the OpenSSL EVP_xxx functions, at least provided as part of CommonCrypto.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any of the MD or SHA hashes you can have OpenSSL compatibility by defining COMMON_DIGEST_FOR_OPENSSL before including CommonDigest.h. So it all depends on the second parameter of your EVP_DigestInit_ex() function call. As an example the Mac App Store signing code that uses SHA1 and 6 "EVP_..." calls can be replaced with the following code:

```
#define COMMON_DIGEST_FOR_OPENSSL
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

    unsigned char digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    if (CC_SHA1([input bytes], [input length], digest)) {
        NSData *newHash = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    }
```